# how to store mongodb distinct or aggregation result to a file

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodump, mongoexport

I am novice to mongodb views. I have a distinct result of mobile numbers, I want to store them in csv file.

Below is my query which is working fine:

```
db.myCollection.distinct('jsonObject.keyIdentifier',{'$and' : [{'jsonObject.responseRaw' : {$not: /<Amount>/}},{'jsonObject.createDate':{$gt: '2020-05-12'} }]})
```

**output: on shell/console**

```
["9898989896",
"9898989897",
"9898989898",
...,
...
]
```

I read some where that I can not just export this result to flat file. I need to create a view first. Then I need to export that view to a file. But I am not able to generate a view.. I tried following

```
db.createView("jsonObject.keyIdentifier","myCollection", [{ $group: { _id: "'$and' : [{'jsonObject.responseRaw' : {$not: /<Amount>/}},{'jsonObject.createDate':{$gt: '2020-05-12'} }]"}}]);
```

Then I write export query:

```
mongoexport -d MongoDB -c jsonObject.keyIdentifier --type=csv -f "_id" -o D:\uploads\DAta\csvFile\report111.csv
```

but instead I got below text in csv file

```
_id
"'$and' : [{'jsonObject.responseRaw' : {$not: /<Amount>/}},{'jsonObject.createDate':{$gt: '2020-05-01'} }]"
```

How to resolve this dilemma ... how can I get the output store to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what worked for me here is `$out` stage of `aggregate` method of `mongodb`. What I did is store a aggregate result to a new `collection` through `$out`(it will be made automatically) and then export it to `csv` by using `mongoexport` statement. Below are the steps:

**1.**

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{'$match':{'$and' : [{'jsonObject.responseRaw' : {'$not': /<Amount>/}},{'jsonObject.createDate':{'$gt': '2020-05-01'}}]}},{'$group':{'_id': '$jsonObject.keyIdentifier'}},{$out: "collectionB"}])
```

**2.**

```
mongoexport -d MyMongoDb -c collectionB  -f _id --csv > D:\uploads\DAta\csvFile\results1111.csv
```

note: here `-f` is the indicating fields; necessary while creating `csv`. I needed only `_id`.

Answer (score 1):

As all you wanted to do is to write your query result to a file & since default `mongoexport` doesn't support any aggregation query rather than creating a view and doing things, you can try as like below :

```
mongo --host='mongodb+srv://uname:password@cluster10-abcde.mongodb.net/dbName?retryWrites=true&w=majority' --eval 'printjson(db.collectionName.aggregate([{"$group" : {"_id" : "", authors: {"$addToSet" : "$author"}}}, {"$project" : {"_id" :0}}]).toArray());' | tail -n 1 > pathToFile.json
```

As in your case since you're doing `.distinct` or similar `$group on no condition i.e; {$group : {_id : ''}}` at the end of execution you'll always have only one document or an array, using `tail -n 1` will help to print only last line which is actual document, Otherwise entire execution stats will be written to the file.

Comment: I am still not able to export my result to external file. I used this `mongo localhost/myMongoDB --eval 'printjson(db.myCollection.aggregate([{'$match':{'$and' : [{'jsonObject.responseRaw' : {'$not': /<Amount>/}},{'jsonObject.createDate':{'$gt': '2020-05-01'}}]}},{'$group':{'_id': '$jsonObject.keyIdentifier'}}]));' | tail -n 1 > D:\uploads\DAta\csvFile\pathToFile.json` But I am getting `The system cannot find the file specified.` here  `myMongoDB` is database and `myCollection` is collection

Comment: @JPG : ‘error says system can’t find the specified file’ !! It has create a new file not sure what it’s searching for is your path correct one ? Did you do ‘cd’ on your path and check if it’s navigating? Also I’ve a question your mongo connection does it work like that ? Without ‘-host’ & port..

Comment: yes path is correct. I cross checked it now again. `Mongodb` is locally installed on windows machine with default port `27017`